# Is the following language regular?

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I believe that $$D = \{w: w \text{ has an equal number of occurrences of the 01 and 10 ranges}\}$$ is regular but can not create regular expression or DFA or NDFA.

Can I have a help.

Comment: If it's equal occurrences of substring 01 and substring 10 - with overlaps OK - then I'd construct the DFA where a state consists of "number of 01 substrings so far minus number of 10 substrings so far" $\in \{ -1, 0, 1 \}$, along with the previously read character (or "nil" for starting state).  I think the only reachable states would be (0,nil), (1,1), (0,1), (0,0), (-1,0).

Comment: Oops, I stand corrected.  I forgot to think about the parts of the substrings and treated them like parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: When you have seen a substring $01$, every subsequent occurrence of $1$ will not increase the number of substrings of the form $10$, but an occurrence of $0$ will. Likewise, when you see a substring $10$, every subsequent occurrence of $0$ will not increase the number of substrings of the form $01$, but an occurrence of $1$ will.